# How can Airflow be used to run distinct tasks of one workflow in separate machines?

Tags: airflow

disclaimer: I'm not (yet) a user of Airflow, just found about it today and I'm starting to explore if it may fit my uses cases.

I have one data processing workflow that is a sequential (not parallel) execution of multiple tasks. However, some of the tasks need to run on specific machines. Can Airflow manage this? What would be the advised implementation model for this use case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this in Airflow with [queues](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#queues). You can tie tasks to a specific queue. Then for each worker on a machine, you can set it to only pickup tasks from select queues.

In code, it would look like this:

```
task_1 = BashOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='task_a',
    ...
)

task_2 = PythonOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='task_b',
    queue='special',
    ...
)
```

Note that there is this setting in airflow.cfg:

```
# Default queue that tasks get assigned to and that worker listen on.
default_queue = default
```

So if you started your workers with this:

```
Server A> airflow worker
Server B> airflow worker --queues special
Server C> airflow worker --queues default,special
```

Then task_1 can be picked up by servers A+C and task_2 can be picked up by servers B+C.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed to know. I'll probably assign each worker a queue named as the node hostname.

Comment: One caveat worth mentioning here is that you can assign a node to multiple queues, but you cannot require multiple queues for one task. Example: if your task requires two programs `special1` and `special2`, you must create a 3rd queue `special1_plus_2` for the task, and assign your `special1` & `special2` enabled node to all three queues.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're running Airflow in Docker, then you should do the following:

1. Set the `queue` name in the DAG file:

   ```
   with DAG(dag_id='dag_v1',
       default_args={
           'retries': 1,
           'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=30),
           'queue':'server-1',
           ...
       },
       schedule_interval=None,
       tags=['my_dags']) as dag:
           ...
   ```
2. Set the default queue in the `docker-compose.yml` file

   ```
   AIRFLOW__OPERATORS__DEFAULT_QUEUE: 'server-1'
   ```
3. Restart the Airflow Webserver, Scheduler etc.

Note: You have to do this for each worker but I assume that you have 1 worker per machine - meaning that each machine needs to have a different `AIRFLOW__OPERATORS__DEFAULT_QUEUE` name and the corresponding DAGs you want to run on that machine need to have the same name for their `queue` (then you can indeed use the `${HOSTNAME}` as the name).