# Is there way to have 3 set of worker nodes (groups) for airflow

Tags: airflow

We are setting up airflow for scheduling/orchestration , currently we have Spark python loads, and non-spark loads in different server and push files to gcp available in another server. Is there an option to decide to which worker nodes the airflow task are submitted? Currently we are using ssh connection to run all work loads. Our processing is mostly on-perm

Usage is celery executor model, How to we make sure that a specific task is run on its appropriate node.

1. task run a non spark server ( no spark binaries available)
2. task 2 executes PySpark submit - (This has spark binaries)
3. Task Push the files created from task 2 from another server/nodes ( Only this has the gcp utilities installed to push the files due to security reason ) .

If create a dag, is it possible to mention the task to execute on set of worker nodes ?

Currently we are having wrapper shell script for each task and making 3 ssh runs to complete these process. We would like to avoid such wrapper shell script rather use the inbuild have pythonOperator , SparkSubmitOperator, SparkJdbcOperator and SFTPToGCSOperator and make sure the specific task runs in specific server or worknodes .

In short , can we have 3 worker node groups and make the task to execute on a group of nodes based on the operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assign a queue to each worker node like

Start the airflow worker with mentioning the queue

```
 airflow worker -q sparkload
 airflow worker -q non-sparkload
 airflow worker -q gcpload
```

The start each task with queue mentioned. Similar thread found as well.

[How can Airflow be used to run distinct tasks of one workflow in separate machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350877/how-can-airflow-be-used-to-run-distinct-tasks-of-one-workflow-in-separate-machin)